# htaccess file mod_rewrite issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Basically this is my structure:

```
/
 - index.html
 - js files ( the ones making http requests to /api/

/api
 - api.php
```

Basicly what im trying to do is to map requests to localhost/api/ to go to localhost/api/api.php

I have tried with the following with no results:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api/
RewriteRule ^/?(api)/? /api/api.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} (PUT|DELETE)
RewriteRule .* /api/api.php
```

Can anyone help me?

Summary: Right now when making http requests I have to set baseUrl to api/api.php/###

I want to to be reached through api/###

Comment: Are sending data with PUT or DELETE only? What I understand is that: Always a request is made in `/api` and is a PUT or DELETE, goes to the api.php. Is this correct?

Comment: @AndreCardoso Right now when its working I make all requests to : baseUrl = "/api/api.php; I want it to work through /api/

My http requests is being sent from the root folder /.

Comment: What directory is your .htaccess in?

Comment: @PanamaJack root folder "/"

Comment: Then first thing you need to remove the rewritebase. Also can you give an example of the full URL you would be calling?

Comment: @PanamaJack My root of the application is localhost:1234/ where ill be calling the api from. The api file is in localhost:1234/api/api.php, and I usually call it like: baseUrl = /api/api.php/movies and such. I want /api/movies/ to be a valid http request