# rewrite url issue htaccess api

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a `/api/` folder under my web root, with a file called `api.php`.

When making requests to `locahost/api/` I want it to be mapped to `localhost/api/api.php` so that I can do HTTP requests like this: `GET localhost/api/movie/1` instead of having to request `localhost/api/api.php/movie/1`.

Here is my current attempt:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^api/([^/]+)/?$ /api/api.php/$1 [L]
```

However, it just gives me a 404 on the requests.

Please help a brother out.

Comment: I think you just want to rewrite everything under api/ to /api/api.php and then let api.php figure out the rest from the uri... at least that's what I do: `RewriteRule /* /index.php`

Although I see you probably have similar logic in there for `/api/api.php/movie/1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htacess file mod\_rewrite issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35466306/htacess-file-mod-rewrite-issue)

Comment: @jhaagsma what does RewriteRule /* /index.php do? Wouldnt it be RewriteRule /api /api.php?

Comment: Yea, sorry, that was one of my own examples where I simply rewrite all data to index.php, which then figures things out from there.

`RewriteRule /api/* /api/api.php` would be the desired equivalent.